# VueJS pushing to an array also pushes the value to another one

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Has any vuejs veteran experience this on VueJS(v2) where you have 2 arrays on a Component, and you push a value to the 1st array and the 2nd array gets the value also WITHOUT TOUCHING IT.

This is the first time I've encountered this, fyi I've been using VueJS for more than 2yrs already.

Additional information I have a VERY VERY similar component with exactly the same `data variables` and it doesn't happen, only on the 2nd Component.

```
array1 = [];
array2 = [];

array1.push('gether');
```

output should be

```
array1 = ['gether'];
array2 = [];
```

WHAT ACTUALLY HAPPENS

```
array1 = ['gether'];
array2 = ['gether'];
```

I've also played with the Google DevTools Vue Debugger.

Adding an entry on the `array1` ONLY also adds the value on the `array2`.

kinda mind boggling

Comment: Are you able to replicate the problem in a CodeSandbox or similar?

Comment: @Lars I haven't tried it yet, but it seems like it happens when I assign the same value to array1 and array2, THEN I added an entry to array1 and then array2 also gets the value magically and vice versa when I add entry to array2, array1 gets the value magically too.

Comment: Can you add some more code ? I think you are coping the array1 to array2 ... Checkout this [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kp7utjrd/2/)

Comment: @Sanmeet Apparrenly my code is way too complicated to be replicated on a codesandbox, but someone has answered my question and it is exactly what is happening.

Comment: @Skeeith22 checkout the answer it also something I experienced in past so I just wanted to see if you are creating  arrays or copying !

Comment: @Sanmeet let me check maybe `splice` is the answer lol

Comment: @Skeeith22 Nope  that's `slice()`  soo close tough :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because arrays in JS are reference values, so when you try to copy it using the = it will only copy the reference to the original array and not the value of the array. To create a real copy of an array, you need to copy over the value of the array under a new value variable. That way this new array does not reference to the old array address in memory.

To achieve this you can use `array.slice()` method as it creates  a new array not a mere reference !

See Example  and understand difference =>

**Using reference (=)**

```
let array = ["some text"]

// Making it equal to main array  and using reference to copy 
array1 = array;
array2 = array;

array1.push('gether');
console.log(array2)
```

**Using `array.slice()` to clone**

```
let array = ["some text"]

// Making it equal to main array and using slice to copy 
array1 = array.slice(); 
array2 = array.slice();

array1.push('gether');

console.log(array2)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you make two arrays equal to the same value, you make them equal by reference.
So

```js
foo = ['a', 'b', 'z']

array1 = foo;
array2 = foo;

array1.push('d');

console.log(array2) //Outputs: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Is expected behaviour.

However that is not the same as the given example in your question. Run snippet below to see the difference.

To avoid this, you can use `slice()` to create a copy of the original array. I added an example to the code snippet.

```js
let foo = ["a", "b"];

let array1 = foo;
let array2 = foo;

array2.push("c");

console.log(foo); // Outputs ["a", "b", "c"]
console.log(array1); // Outputs ["a", "b", "c"]

let array3 = [];
let array4 = [];

array4.push("a");

console.log(array3); // Outputs []
console.log(array4); // Outputs ["a"]

let bar = ["a", "b"];

let array5 = bar.slice();

bar.push("c");

console.log(bar); // Outputs ["a", "b", "c"]
console.log(array5); // Outputs ["a", "b"]
```

Comment: Actually this is what is happening, it is exactly what you mentioned. I've assigned exactly the same values on both arrays.

Comment: How can I make it so that it won't reflect on the other array? is there a way or something?

Comment: @Skeeith22 i added a solution to the answer.